# How to remove bottom link from tinymce?

Tags: tinymce

i want to remove

tag from tinymce,

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
theme_advanced_path : false,
theme_advanced_resizing : true
});
```

please see following image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you may add the setup configuration parameter to your tinymce configuration like this

```
setup : function(ed) {

  ed.on('init', function(evt)
  {
    $('#'+ed.id+'_path_row').hide();
  });
},
```